# OData read inside a read success handler not working

Tags: sapui5

I'm new to SAPUI5 and I'm having problems...

When I use a `read` function to get a value from an OData service, I'm trying to use another `read` function inside the success function, using a filter with the value that I obtained from the first read.

Is this even possible?

Up to now, it just seems like it reads successfully, but then it doesn't execute the next read.

```js
var filters = new Array();
var first_Filter = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
  path: "userId",
  operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,
  value1: userId
});
filters.push(first_Filter);
this.getOwnerComponent().getModel().read("/users", {
  filters: la_filters,
  success: function(oData, response) {
    var data = oData.results[0];
    var jobid = data.jobId;
    var filters2 = new Array();
    var second_Filter2 = new sap.ui.model.Filter({
      path: "idJob",
      operator: sap.ui.model.FilterOperator.EQ,
      value1: jobid
    });
    filters2.push(second_Filter2);
    this.getOwnerComponent().getModel().read("/jobs", {
      filters: la_filters2,
      success: function(oData2) { 
        // read odata ,get value and pass it on...
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the `this` inside the second `read` is not the correct one.

save a reference to `this` (outside the first read) like `var that = this;` and use it to make the second `read` like

```
that.getOwnerComponent().getModel().read("/jobs", {
  filters: la_filters2,
  success: function(oData2) { 
    // read odata ,get value and pass it on...
  }
});
```